# Problems saving values by SharedPreferences and editing them

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I save the values (integer) to SharedPreferences, but when I call them to apply them to some numeric operations, I found the result to be 0 (default value is 0)

Also, when I went back from the last Activity to first one and choose a RadioButton next to next, I found the result is OK!

So what's the problem?

MainActivity (it's just a Button to next "first Page")

**First Page:**

```
buttonp21.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        RadioGroup radGrp = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.RadioGroupp2);
        int checkedRadioButtonID = radGrp.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
        radGrp.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int id) {

                switch (id) {
                    case R.id.s4:
                        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences4 = getSharedPreferences("Data",MODE_PRIVATE);
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor4 = sharedPreferences4.edit();
                        editor4.putInt("KEY_POINTS2", 1);
                        editor4.apply();
                        break;
                    case R.id.s5:
                        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences5 = getSharedPreferences("Data",MODE_PRIVATE);
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor5 = sharedPreferences5.edit();
                        editor5.putInt("KEY_POINTS2", 2);
                        editor5.apply();
                        break;
                    case R.id.s6:
                        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences6 = getSharedPreferences("Data",MODE_PRIVATE);
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor6 = sharedPreferences6.edit();
                        editor6.putInt("KEY_POINTS2", 3);
                        editor6.apply();
                        break;
                }


            }
        });
        if(checkedRadioButtonID == -1){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "please choose", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}
        else {
            Intent i1 = new Intent(Page1.this, Page2.class);
            startActivity(i1);
        }

    }
});

buttonp22.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        Intent i1 = new Intent(Page1.this, MaineActivity.class);
        startActivity(i1);

    }
});
```

And next exists 20 activities like "First Page".... (just different on id of Buttons, RadioButtons, GroupButtons, pages names, and keys)

**Last Page:**

```
infoo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int DEFAULT = 0;
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("Data", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        int p1 = sharedPreferences.getInt("KEY1", DEFAULT);  
        int p2 = sharedPreferences.getInt("KEY2", DEFAULT);
        int p3 = sharedPreferences.getInt("KEY3", DEFAULT);  
        int p4 = sharedPreferences.getInt("KEY4", DEFAULT);  
        int p5 = sharedPreferences.getInt("KEY5", DEFAULT);  
        int p6 = sharedPreferences.getInt("KEY6", DEFAULT);  
        int p7 = sharedPreferences.getInt("KEY7", DEFAULT); 
        int p8 = sharedPreferences.getInt("KEY8", DEFAULT);  
        int p9 = sharedPreferences.getInt("KEY9", DEFAULT); 
        int p10 = sharedPreferences.getInt("KEY10", DEFAULT); 
        int p11 = sharedPreferences.getInt("KEY12", DEFAULT); 
        int p11 = sharedPreferences.getInt("KEY12", DEFAULT); 
        int p13 = sharedPreferences.getInt("KEY13", DEFAULT);
        int p14 = sharedPreferences.getInt("KEY14", DEFAULT); 
        int p15 = sharedPreferences.getInt("KEY15", DEFAULT); 
        int p16 = sharedPreferences.getInt("KEY16", DEFAULT); 
        int p17 = sharedPreferences.getInt("KEY17", DEFAULT); 
        int p18 = sharedPreferences.getInt("KEY18", DEFAULT); 
        int p19 = sharedPreferences.getInt("KEY19", DEFAULT); 
        int p20 = sharedPreferences.getInt("KEY20", DEFAULT); 

        int total = p1 + p2 + p3 + p4 + p5 + p6 + p7 + p8 + p9 + p10 + p11 + p12 + p13 + p14 + p15 + p16 + p17 + p18 + p19 + p20;
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "" + total , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    }
});
```

Comment: Did you try using `commit()` instead of `apply()`? The former is synchronous, while the latter is asynchronous. Maybe you were too fast and it still didn't finish writing. When you checked again, all was written.

Comment: when using commit() : Consider using apply() instead; commit writes its data to persistent storage immediately, whereas apply will handle it in the background,, its ok?

Comment: emmm same problems with using commit (),
Its when writing as u say ...
Any solutions with this problem ?!

Comment: Then I guess I did not understand the problem. You said that the first time you check the saved values it's all 0s, and the second time it's all OK, didn't you? It seems like a synchronization problem to me.

Comment: first time : when i click on result button its all 0, so i back by click on backb button to Page  20 then 19 then....1. and repeat the chooses its all ok, In addition its sometimes app remember last values!! (when i repeat from begin)

Comment: even when using commit() -_-

Comment: and what about "Consider using apply() instead; commit writes its data to persistent storage immediately, whereas apply will handle it in the background.." on my code when i use commit()!!

Comment: Let me try to figure out why do you create all those SharedPreferences objects (which you seem to leave open). The mantra is `open, use, close`. Never leave an object open, And never create more objects than you need.

Comment: thats last update of my code hhh i try to Solve the problem by much ways
and "SharedPreferences objects" one of them -_-

Comment: Having multiple objects all operating on the same file can be a real pain. And consider closing an object as soon as you used it.

Comment: ok thank you :), how i can close object of sharedpreferences?

Comment: As with any other object: `yourObject = null;`

Comment: ok thank u, i will rewrite the code and see the result.

Comment: the same problem...
but : when i back from last activity >>>>by back option of mobile not by button on app<<<<<<
to pervious activity to pervious activity to.... first activity
and chose again from radiogroup (even i changed the chose) and click next to next activity and choose, click next.....
to last activity click on result button .. result all is ok!!!
and when i prepared that experience with >>by back button on app<<<
the result is 0!

were is the problem -_-

Comment: its look like some problem on Cycle life Activity and way of save to SharedPreferences....

Comment: Sorry, your English construction is hard to follow - I think you are following your motherlanguage construction rules. So, if the problem arises by pressing the back button, don't. Have a "Save settings" button which simply closes the Settings preferences after saving them. Or am I missing something? Are you trying to customize the PreferenceScreen by overriding the default behaviour?

Comment: The problem arises by pressing the next button, (its ok with back button)  no values stored in SharedPreferences when i pressing the next button.. sorry for my langyage:)

Comment: I think i dont have to do somthing to save setting when pressing the next button??,, because the values store on SharedPreferences when i click on radiobutton and pressing the next button, but its doesnt work (not store)

Comment: But... tell me: Why `And next exists 20 activities like "First Page"...`?! Why do you need 1 "page" per each setting? Can't you do that within a single "page"? Moreover, couldn't you simply use a PreferenceScreen, instead of doing that on your own? So to be sure that it works flawlessly.

Comment: yes i need much pages, how i can do PreferenceScreen with radio button?

Comment: i need much pages because on each page there is difference chooses and each choose has a value integer (1,2,3.......)

Comment: After the user chooses I collect those numbers

Comment: Have a peek into `android listpreference`